# Resolve getItemType in Generics class

Tags: java, generics

I need help resolving this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at GenericsLab.getItemType(GenericsLab.java:14)     at
>   GenericLabTester.main(GenericLabTester.java:18)

I am trying to write a Generic class and a class tester but not sure how to resolve this error.

Here is my main generic class:

```
public class GenericsLab<T> {
    Object item;

    public GenericsLab(T Object) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    Object getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    String getItemType() {
        return item.getClass().getName();//line 14.
    }
}
```

Here is my GenericsTester class:

```
import java.util.List;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GenericLabTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List list = new ArrayList(2);

        GenericsLab integerItem = new GenericsLab(100);
        list.add(integerItem);

        System.out.println("Type for integerItem is: " + integerItem.getItemType());//line 18

        System.out.println("Value for integerItem is: " + integerItem.getItem());
    }
}
```

the goal is to properly make use of Java Generics for its element types.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GenericsLab<T> {

    T item;

    public GenericsLab(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    T getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    String getItemType() {
        return item.getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `T getItem()` I think